# How to assign velocities using a maxwell-boltzmann distribution in Java

Tags: java

I am currently working on a model of gas particles in a container. When I initialise the particles I am currently giving them all the same magnitude of velocity (Varying +/- directions).. I need to find a way to change this so that the velocities follow a maxwell boltzmann distribution.

Does anyone have any idea how to go about this?

Comment: Do you need help with assigning a value of something to something or how to calculate velocities or how this maxwell boltzmann thing works?

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia entry for [Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution), meet [java.lang.math](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html).  Kidding aside, I assume you have an understanding of how the distribution works.  Here is a forum discussion on how to [do the calculations in C](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/162675-random-number/).  And here is a web site where the researchers actually made a java applet that shows [the little balls bouncing around](http://www.sas.upenn.edu/rappegroup/htdocs/Education/MB/index.html) in a way defined by that distribution.  They might be able to help you out.  For a big hint on how to do this, check out [Question 34](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/21function/) in the Web Exercises section.